# How to reload page without losing any inserted (div) data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i have multiple  tags, which is set as editable (contentEditable="true"). is there any way to store contents in divs before load and paste the same after reload or any alternative way to do this?. I am very new in the programming field

```
<div contentEditable="true" id="main" key="main" class="main" >  
<div contentEditable="true" id="div1" onfocusout="myFunction()"><p>sample para</p></div>
<div contentEditable="true" id="div2" onfocusout="myFunction()"><p>sample para</p></div>
</div >



window.onload = function()
    {
        var a = sessionStorage.getItem('main');
            //alert(a);
            document.getElementById("main").value = a; 
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("main", $('#main').val());
    }
```

I tried this, but it is only for forms with known input field

My body html looks like

```
   <body>
    <div>Math in TeX notation</div>

 <div contentEditable="true" id="main" key="main" class="main" >  
    <div contentEditable="true" id="div1" onfocusout="myFunction()"><p>sample para</p></div>
    <div contentEditable="true" id="div2" onfocusout="myFunction()"><p>sample para</p></div>
</div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save any data to session storage and use it later with JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function () {
  const content = sessionStorage.getItem('main');
  if (content) {
     document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = content;
  }
}

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  sessionStorage.setItem("main", document.getElementById("main").innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: After puting this, two div tags are lost in my html view. i edited my question with my body html. please suggest, what i missed

Comment: @sam I added condition on window onload event to check if divs content is stored.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked this together, it works for me (using Firefox), i tested it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="memo-pad">
        <pre id="memo" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="storeUserMemo(this.id);"></pre>
    </div>

    <script>

        function storeUserMemo(id) {
            let memo = document.getElementById("memo").innerHTML;
            localStorage.setItem("userMemo", memo);
        }

        function getUserMemo() {
            let memo;
            if (localStorage.getItem("userMemo")) {
                memo = localStorage.getItem("userMemo");
            } else {
                memo = "Please write something here!";
            }
            document.getElementById("memo").innerHTML = memo;
        }

        function clearLocal() {
            localStorage.clear();
            document.getElementById("memo").innerHTML = "Please write something here!";
        }

        getUserMemo();

        let memo = document.getElementById("memo");
        memo.addEventListener("input", function () {
            console.log("Wer ändert hier sein Memo?")
        });


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Whatever you put in there survives the page reload now.